# How to type a curried `map`?

Tags: typescript, currying, map-function

I'm trying to type a curried `map` function in TypeScript. Here is the JavaScript equivalent:

```js
const double = n => n * 2;
const map = f => arr => arr.map(f);
const doubleArr = map(double);

console.log(doubleArr([1, 2, 3]));
// ↳ [2, 4, 6]
```

Ideally, TypeScript should be able to infer, that after supplying `double` to `map`, `doubleArray` takes in an array of numbers and returns an array of numbers.

Here is what I tried:

```
const double = (n: number) => n * 2;
const map = (f: Function) => (arr: Array<any>) => arr.map(f);
```

But, TypeScript complains about `f` inside of `map`:

```
Argument of type 'Function' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: any, index: number, array: any[]) => unknown'.
  Type 'Function' provides no match for the signature '(value: any, index: number, array: any[]): unknown'.
```

How would you type this function in TypeScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following declarations:

```
const double = (n: number) => n * 2;
const map = <A, R>(f: (arg: A) => R) => (arr: A[]) => arr.map(f);
const doubleArr = map(double); // (arr: number[]) => number[]

console.log(doubleArr([1, 2, 3]));
// ↳ [2, 4, 6]
```

[Playground sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=6&pc=15#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJiArgIwDYFMYF4YAowBcMYiAtsugE4CU2AfMTAFQwBMA3AFCiSykCGAB2wwAPAEEANDABKdXADMiufpQDmRcbSwMZ2hisqVNAbQC6+mKsoA6AYMXUuPaPCRp04oyPu4EKDCcYAHpgvGsiEnIqc0soikpzTm5wCBAMG1QQNT93DC9KXBMARmlWaQBmCydOUJhAZsIYE3KYABZpADYzIA)

---

Explanation: `A` and `R` are [generic type parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html). `map(double)` returns a function with signature `(arr: number[]) => number[]`, because  TS is able to [infer](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html) from `double` typings, that `A` and `R` both can only be `number` here.

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you point me to the correct section in the docs that explains the `<A, R>` part? Or could you amend your answer explaining what's going on here?

Answer (score 2):

You can declare an interface and then pass it  instead of `Function`

```
interface ArrFunction<T> {
    (n: T): T
}

const double = (n: number) => n * 2;
const map = (f: ArrFunction<any>) => (arr: Array<any>) => arr.map(f);
```

Comment: This does compile now, but it doesn't correctly infer the type of `doubleArr`. `const doubleArr: (arr: any[]) => any[]`

Comment: you can improve it by doing next, `const map = <T>(f: ArrFunction<T>) => (arr: Array<T>) => arr.map(f);`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function `map` with two parameters: array and function and when to want to use this function you should give an item from array to this function.

```
const double = (n: number) => n * 2;
const map = (arr: Array<any>, f: Function) => arr.map((item: any) => f(item));
map([1, 2, 3], double)
```

Comment: Hi Kamil, thank you for your help. I was looking for a _curried_ `map` though!